# WCF ServiceActivationException Confusion

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-6

I have a WCF service which works perfectly when deployed in our dev and test environments, but which falls over in the production environment.

When attempting to browse to the service, the following exception is thrown (inner exception type is InvalidDataContractException):

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/IL.Party.WS/Party.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Type 'IL.Party.MS.Person' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute..]

I can't figure out what's going on here. All three environments are Windows Server 2003, IIS6 and .NET 3.5. On the server where the service fails, I have gone as far as deleting the temp. ASP.NET files to force a recompile. The same code is deployed across all three environments. If 'IL.Party.MS.Person' was not serializable I would expect to get this error in all three environments. The Person type has fields of type string, int, DateTime and decimal - so nothing out of the ordinary and definitely serializable.

Does anyone have an idea as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Is the production .NET 3.5, and your DEV/TEST 3.5 SP1, by any chance??

Comment: Ah good one, yes that is the case. How come such a simple type is being deemed unserializable pre SP1?

Comment: This seems to be the answer: DataContract Serializer gets way easier by relaxing/removing the ned for [DataContract] and [DataMember] on types. It's POCO (Plain Ol' CLR Object) time, people. (from http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HiddenGemsNotTheSameOld35SP1Post.aspx)

Comment: I still prefer to be explicit and put [DataContract] and [DataMember] on my classes - just to clearly state my intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marc_s actually answered this in the comments.

But it looks like the reason is the changes in the data contract serializer.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HiddenGemsNotTheSameOld35SP1Post.aspx

Comment: Correct, thanks marc_s. Thanks Shiraz for the extra info. Busy upgrading production to .NET 3.5 SP1 - will report back on whether this fixes it.

Comment: Working as expected after upgrading to .NET 3.5 SP1. Note that the real cause was the missing [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes, which should be added, as mentioned by foosnazzy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try recycling the App Pools?  It's best practice to explicit mark you DataContracts so I would apply those attributes as well.  Is it possible that your vdir http activation is misconfigured?

Comment: Recycled, iisreset, server reboot. Pretty much covered my bases there. It's probably the fact that in the production environment .NET 3.5 is isntalled, while in dev and test its .NET 3.5 SP1 (see above).

Answer (score 0):

This can be a possible reason. I encountered this error for same reason mentioned below

```
Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (258187264 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests.  To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element.
```